# Reading a MatLab (mat) file with VNL

Tags: c++, mat-file

I've been given a `.mat` file (three dimensions, single precision floating point), which I'd like to read using [`VXL`](http://vxl.sourceforge.net/).  `VNL` has a few classes/functions for doing this, but I've not found any examples demonstrating their use.  I've pieced the following together from [the header file](https://public.kitware.com/vxl/doc/release/core/vnl/html/vnl__matlab__read_8h_source.html), but no data seems to be read in, and when I ask for the dimensions, I get what appears to be uninitialized junk (though some data from the header is read).

```
#include <vcl_cstdlib.h>
#include <vcl_iostream.h>
#include <vcl_fstream.h>
#include <vnl/vnl_matlab_read.h>
#include <vnl/vnl_vector.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

  if (2 != argc)
    {
    std::cerr << "Provide a file." << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  const char * fileName = argv[1];

  vcl_filebuf fileBuffer;
  if (!fileBuffer.open(fileName,vcl_ios::in))
    {
    std::cerr << "There was a problem opening the file." << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  vcl_istream stream(&fileBuffer);
  vnl_matlab_readhdr read(stream);

  vcl_cout << read.name() << vcl_endl; // Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: (date and time)
  vcl_cout << read.rows() << vcl_endl; // 1094852661
  vcl_cout << read.cols() << vcl_endl; // 774905933

  vnl_vector<float> data;
  vnl_matlab_read_or_die(stream, data, fileName);
  std::cout << data.size() << std::endl; // 0

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

I can't tell if I'm using the class incorrectly, or if perhaps `VNL` can't deal with multidimensional arrays?

Comment: And just a note, [vxl] would probably have been a good tag for this question, but I don't have enough reputation to propose it.  A quick search shows a fair number of other questions about `vxl`, but I don't know how popular a topic should be to justify a tag.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Not all MAT-Files are using the same format, it has been changed several times. Reading junk might be an attempt to read a compressed MAT-File with a library which does not support compression.

As I am unable to find any reasonable documentation for the library you chose, I can only recommend an alternative. When saving the MAT-File in matlab, specify the format `-v7.3` which is the most recent one. Doing so, Matlab will write a gzip compressed [HDF5](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) file, which comes with [an API for C++](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/)

In case you don't have access to Matlab, use Octave to convert your Mat-Files to the most recent format. Here the option for the `save` function is called `-hdf5` and not `-7.3`

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, @Daniel.  I ended up using a workaround in R.  I read the images in using `R.matlab`, then saved them as a volume using `oro.nifti`.  I could then read them into ITK.  This is pretty cumbersome, though--I'll give your method a try next time I get a batch of images.  +1 for the C++ API documentation!